# Fixed + Fluid Bootstrap Template with Off-canvas Sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I found this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Sm05XRCo7x) code for Fixed + Fluid Bootstrap Template with Off-canvas Sidebar.

My tests shows it works well on Chrome and Firefox, In Internet Explorer it crashes it, in Windows Safari the content column is shifted to left leaving white space equal to the sidebar width as shown in image below.

Is there any fix for this, I have not tested other browsers but I got interested in the idea.

My guess in IE is the problem with the css Calc line:

```
width:calc(100% + 220px);
```

The code is here also:

CSS:

```
body,html,.row-offcanvas {
  height:100%;
}

body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#sidebar {
  width: inherit;
  min-width: 220px;
  max-width: 220px;
  background-color:#f5f5f5;
  float: left;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  overflow-y:auto;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
#main {
  height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}

/*
 * off Canvas sidebar
 * --------------------------------------------------
 */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .row-offcanvas {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    width:calc(100% + 220px);
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left
  {
    left: -220px;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left.active {
    left: 0;
  }

  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div><!--/.navbar -->

<div class="row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
  <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar-offcanvas">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3>Sidebar (fixed)</h3>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Section</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Section</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Section</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Section</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Section</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Section</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Section</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Section</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Section</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Section</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <p class="visible-xs">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="offcanvas"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></button>
          </p>
          <h2>Fixed + Fluid Bootstrap Template with Off-canvas Sidebar</h2>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12"><div class="well"><p>Shrink the browser width to make the sidebar collapse off canvase.</p></div></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4"><div class="well"><p>4 cols</p></div></div>
              <div class="col-md-4"><div class="well"><p>4 cols</p></div></div>
              <div class="col-md-4"><div class="well"><p>4 cols</p></div></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6"><div class="well"><p>6 cols, 6 small cols</p></div></div>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6"><div class="well"><p>6 cols, 6 small cols</p></div></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6"><div class="well">4 cols, 6 small cols</div></div>
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6"><div class="well">4 cols, 6 small cols</div></div>
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12"><div class="well">4 cols, 12 small cols</div></div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div><!--/row-offcanvas -->
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

[image]